# Extract data from JSON array to ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to extract data from JSON array using Reactjs. So far I've successfully extracted objects which are not inside array. But how can I extract items from array?

Comment: Have you tried `{this.state.data.stats.map((stat, i) =>  {
 return <div key={i}>  {stat.base_stat} </div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.data.stats.map(function (stat, i) {
 return key={'stat-'+i}>{stat.base_stat}
```

this is wrong syntax... try this:

```
{this.state.data.stats.map(function (stat, i) {
 return <div key={'stat-'+i}>{stat.base_stat}</div>});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at what you're trying to do and I think this is what you're trying to do, more or less:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      height: '',
      weight: '',
      stats: [],
    }
  }

  getData() {
    return fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        const { name, height, weight, stats } = responseJson;
        this.setState({ name, height, weight, stats });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  renderStats() {
    return this.state.stats.map(s =>
      <div key={s.stat.name}>
        {s.stat.name}: {s.base_stat}
      </div>)
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="Info">
        <div id="title" className="title">{this.state.name}</div>
        <div id="parameters" className="parameters">
          <tr><td>Height:</td>&nbsp;<td className="data">{this.state.height}</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Weight:</td>&nbsp;<td className="data">{this.state.weight}</td></tr>
          <br />
          <div>Stats:</div>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div id="stats" className="stats">
          {this.renderStats()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```

Couple of things:

1. You don't need to call `setState` multiple times. Batch your calls.
2. Make the this.state at least spell out the data it expects
3. Use a key that's meaningful if you can. You should only resort to using the array index position if you've nothing better. In this case I used the stat name.